# Code implementation in php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to understand the code and I am confused to understand the code at this point below.  in the **first example** I want to fetch data from the database and display them as drop-down list but unfortunately it is not displaying anything, and in the second example everything is working fine (fetching data displaying as the drop-down list) bu the problem is that I cant understand the code in the second example it looks much more complicated than the first example. So I want to correct my first example and after that I can rebuilt the second example based on the first one.

First table is department (ID, persondepartment, Description)
Second table board ( personboard, description)
ps: this is for my project so I dont care about Security

**First Example - Not Working**

```
<td>Department</td>
        <td>
            <select name='persondepartment' ID="dept">
            <option ID="0">-- Select Department --</option>
            <?php
            mysql_connect('localhost', 'data_datab', 'password');
            mysql_select_db ("data");

            $getalldepartments = "SELECT * FROM department";
                WHILE ($viewdepartments = mysql_fetch_array(
                    $getalldepartments)){
            ?>
            <option ID="<?php echo $viewdepartments['ID'];?>
            "> <?php echo $viewdepartments ['persondepartment'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        </td>
```

**Second Example - Working**

```
<td>Board</td>
   <td>
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'data_datab', 'password');
mysql_select_db ("data");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM board";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='personboard'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['personboard'] . "'>" . $row['personboard'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</td>
```

Comment: You might want to look into the more updated (and way more secure) ``mysqli`` library or ``pdo``. the old mysql implementation is only there for legacy code bases and far, far outdated.

Comment: In the 2nd example you are iterating over the results but in the first example you are repeating an sql query and missing the actual db query: $result = mysql_query($sql);. The idea is to run an sql command, get the results and iterate over the results. Secondly, WHILE should be lowercase if used as PHP code.

Comment: $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "data_datab", "password", "data");

Comment: I have tried this connection but is not working, I am not good in php.

Comment: if you use mysqli_ you have to also make all the other functions mysqli_ which means go find a mysqli_ example because you can't just guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
$getalldepartments = "SELECT * FROM department";
```

to:

```
$getalldepartments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM department");
```

and consider to use `mysqli` instead of deprecated `mysql` extension.

---

Correct version with `PDO`

```
<td>Department</td>
<td>
    <select name="persondepartment" id="dept">
        <option value="0">-- Select Department --</option>
<?php
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data', 'data_datab', 'password');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo '<option value="">' . $e->getMessage() . '</option>';
        }

        $getalldepartments = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM department");
        while ($viewdepartments = $getalldepartments->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
        <option value="<?= $viewdepartments['ID']; ?>"><?= $viewdepartments['persondepartment']; ?></option>
<?php
        }
?>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: or PDO which would be even better.

Comment: No, it is not displaying anything ;(

Comment: @Shkolla, Updated my answer, so you will see error, if any, in the dropdown list.

Comment: @spirit  Yep with PDO worked exactly, I have changed the code for both departments and board and YES it is working. By the way I have a question about the connection with PDO, Can i make a separate file so i can only call in the feature ? something like request("config.php") ??

Comment: @Shkolla, if it works than please consider to mark my answer as a correct one. And yes, you can do that. In fact, it is the right approach to make a connection in one place and use that connection everywhere in your programm.

Comment: In that case, you must monitor variable scope for `$pdo` object. [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)